# vb.net multi timer stopwatch

Tags: vb.net, timer

how Datagridview will generate a timer to fit the line of each want to display time on the line?

How click a button to create a timer to calculate the time remaining to the next low?
The timer is each should be created. to suit row
Continuously have to do the countdown.
Dynamic timer_tick How to make several?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBm9U.png)

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    TimerCount = DataGridView2.RowCount - 1

    Dim tmrTimeNew(TimerCount) As Timer
    tmrTimeNew(TimerCount) = New Timer
    tmrTimeNew(TimerCount).Interval = 1000
    tmrTimeNew(TimerCount).Enabled = True
    AddHandler tmrTimeNew(TimerCount)???.Tick, AddressOf tmrTimeNew_Tick2

End Sub

Private Sub **tmrTimeNew_Tick(TimerCount)???**(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    'MsgBox(TimerCount)
    '현재시간 라벨에 보여주기
    With DataGridView2
        .Rows(TimerCount).Cells(0).Value = TimerCount & " saniye"
    End With


End Sub
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you want to do but I'm not a big fan of creating a bunch of timer especially if they all have the same interval. You could end up with a lot of running threads. Threads are good if you have one per cpu or if you need to wait for an other process. I would create one timer that pulls from a todo list. Your button would just need to add to that todo list.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Easy to understand the question? I corrected. If you show me an example. Thank you

Comment: The variable TimerCount is misleading, it's actually the row index that you want to update. Add/remove these row index to a list. Have only one timer running and in the timer loop in that list to update the wanted rows.